# How to refresh a portion of a webpage every N seconds

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with dynamic values inside. I need it to refresh every "n" seconds without refreshing the page. I tried using the load function but was not able to get it working.

This is my HTML

```
<tbody id="leaderboardUpdate">
        @foreach ($quizLeaderBoard as $key => $leaderBoardValue)
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{ ++$key }}</th>
              <td><a target="_blank" href="{{ url('profile') . '/' . $leaderBoardValue->user->username }}">{{ $leaderBoardValue->user->displayName() }}</a></td>
              <td>{{ $leaderBoardValue->totalScore }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load function is the correct way of doing it.

```
function startTimer() {
  //do your stuff
  $('#leaderboardUpdate').load('/remote/content.html  #leaderboardUpdate > *');
  //repeats itself after 4 seconds
  setTimeout(startTimer, 4000);
}

startTimer();
```

Change "/remote/content.html" for the actual page URL where your table is. Just make sure you obviously have the jQuery plugin in your page header.

In the above, 30000 is in milliseconds so equal to 30 seconds.

Using setTimeout has the advantage that if the connection hangs for some time you will not get tons of pending requests since a new one will only be sent after the previous one finished.

In order to have a recurring event of the function, you need to put everything in a function that setTimer will recall after his own execution.

Comment: i tried this code but the whole website reloads inside the leaderboard div

Comment: in that case you can respecify the good ID  (just updated my answer) give this a shot ;-)

Comment: it works but it only executed once

Comment: You just need to nest it inside a function that calls it self. I made the adjustments.

Comment: thank you! it works. I just put the code in the submit button of my quiz but that works also!

Comment: Perfect glad it worked ;-)

Comment: one last question, it displays twice how do i prevent this? i added `.empty()` function but it's still the same

Comment: You just need to add a selector at the end like this: 
/remote/content.html  #leaderboardUpdate > *
so you grab the content and not the parent. I updated the above code

Comment: still won't work but ill figure it out. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use js function  `setInterval()` to get realtime data.And use ajax to get data from server.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     getNewData();
     self.setInterval("getNewData()",2000);  
 });

 function getNewData(){    
     //at this function,you can get data from server and split html.
 }
```

Comment: how do i get data from the server?